# Is eval the defmacro of javascript?

Tags: javascript, lisp

In Common Lisp, `defmacro` basically allows us to build our own DSL.

I read [this page](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/acorn.html) today and it explains something cleverly done:

> But I wasn't about to write out all these boring predicates myself, so I defined a function that, given a list of words, builds up the text for such a predicate automatically, and then evals it to produce a function.

Which just looks like `defmacro` to me.

Is `eval` the `defmacro` of javascript? Could it be used as such?

Comment: `defmacro` sounds like a preprocessor directive / macro.  `eval` is just a function which allows you to execute javascript dynamically, at runtime.  I guess you *could* write an interpreter in it, but it wouldn't be natively supported in any JS environment - you'd have to make a call to your code, and encode everything inside a JS string.

Comment: @DanielB Well, `defmacro` *is* a preprocessor macro in Common Lisp. It's what makes CLisp so famous and powerful. That's why using `eval` in a similar way in javascript seems appealing to me, even though it's *technically* not implemented in the same way. I'd just like some community opinion about this.

Comment: I understand, my point is that `defmacro` allows you to code macros "naturally" in lisp, without going into any special mode, while with `eval`, you'd have to essentially code inside a string (e.g. how a regular expression is used in C#).  It's certainly doable (and has been done before - e.g. coffeescript can be turned into JS using JS itself, and  `eval`'d dynamically) although I suspect you will find heavy resistance in the community, who have been trained to avoid `eval` like the plague.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can, but it's more dangerous.

`defmacro` has three main features:

1. It runs at compile time;
2. It is a genuine in-place substitution; and
3. Because of the whole nature of Lisp syntax, it works at an AST level, not a source-code level.

By contrast, `eval`:

1. Executes at runtime;
2. Is not an in-place substitution; and
3. Works with strings.

Why does this matter?

First, `eval` has a speed penalty: because it has to evaluate its arguments every single time it's called, instead of just once at compile time, you'll have a speed hit on each run of the program.

Second, there is no compile-time validation that the `eval` is actually getting passed something sane.  You can have a horrible syntax error in your `eval` argument (or, worse, a horrible syntax error *only when called in certain ways*), but it won't be caught until runtime far down the road.  Because Lisp macros are compile-time, you can't have that.  Your macro might not work, mind you, but it'll compile by definition to something valid.

Third, `eval` has serious safety issues compared to `defmacro`.  Because Lisp macros work with the AST, there's a high degree of safety.  No matter what argument you supply the macro at runtime, those arguments can't allow a malicious caller to "escape" the macro, or call malicious code.  That's not true of `eval`: if you don't think through your string escapes very, very carefully, and you allow any form of user-generated input into the `eval` string, you're risking allowing malicious code to run.

*Okay, but, whatever,* I can hear you say.  *The user would have to do that to himself, and it's already his browser, so why care?*

Because there are lots of ways to inject scripts in that situation.  Cross-site script requests, for example, or forgetting to escape a string properly that you store in a database.  There are *lots* of ways of getting malicious values into those macros--and the moment that happens, your users' data is toast.

Finally, even if *all of that* doesn't dissuade you, JavaScript's `eval` in particular is simply less powerful.  There are odd ways that it interacts with the enclosing variable scope and the global variable scope, for example, and there's no sane way to do the equivalent of Common Lisp's `gensym` for variable hygiene.

Can you use `eval` in *some* of the places you might use `defmacro`?  Sure.  But they are hardly interchangeable, and I hope that the above explanation makes it clear why absolutely zero good JavaScript frameworks I know use `eval`.

Instead, if you really find yourself wanting macros, go find a compiles-to-JavaScript language that has them, such as ClojureScript.  That way, you'll get the benefits of Lisp macros without the drawbacks of `eval`.

Answer (score 3):

As `eval` can execute arbitrary javascript I'm sure you could put something together similar to a macro system. That being said, javascript is not *homoiconic* in the same way as Common Lisp or Scheme. Homoiconicity(?) is the fancy term for the old list mantra of "Code as data". A macro system transforms code. This is very natural when you can maniplate code in the same way that you manipulate other data because *everything* is a list (LISt Proccessing). We can list many ways in which javascript "is a lisp", but it does not treat code as data.

In a lisp macro system, we manipulate lists. In a "javascript macro system" (notice the quotes) we have to manipulate strings or some complicated AST.

There's a famous antecdote where someone is giving a talk on all the ways that Python is a lisp "first class functions blah blah blah". At the end, John McCarthy (inventor of Lisp) raises his hand and asks "Does it treat code as data?" *Zing*.

In conclusion, `eval` could probably be used to tack a macro system onto javascript. But it would not be as natural as Common Lisp's `defmacro`.

Comment: Lisp advocates' claims notwithstanding, conflating code with data is not a good thing and never has been. It's a massive security hole that's been responsible for billions of dollars worth of losses over the last couple decades. Every time you hear about a major website or a bank or credit card processor that got hacked through SQL injection and disclosed the user data of millions of customers, that's because some programmer somewhere *did not properly separate code from data.*

Comment: @MasonWheeler That's not all what "code as data" means. It has nothing to do with security. It means you can manipulate your code using the same tools you use to manipulate your data. In Lisp, code and data have the same form: lists. I can write a macro to manipulate a function in the same way I could write a function to manipulate a list or tree. 

SQL injections happen when you don't sanitize input. Including raw SQL in your code isn't "code as data".

Comment: No, SQL injections do not happen when you "don't sanitize your input."  They happen when you mix data (user input) and code (SQL queries) together as the same thing instead of treating them correctly, as two completely separate concepts, by using parameters. [Sanitizing is of very limited usefulness compared to doing it right by properly separating code and data.](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies)

Comment: @MasonWheeler I agree. There are better ways to handle user input than "sanitizing" a string and inserting it into the SQL. However, the issue you're talking about is completely unrelated to the Lisp concept of "code as data".

Comment: In fact, Lisp-style "code as data" (as the basis of macros) is one way to avoid SQL injections, without having to write clunky-looking code. For example, I plan to write an SQL data-access module that allows you to write queries like `(select * from foo where (lcase name) = ,(string-downcase name))`, which will get turned into `"select * from foo where lcase(name) = ?"`, with the value filled in by the `(string-downcase name)` expression. Try doing that with other languages!